# Android-Continuously change the text of TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am designing a image puzzle game.
When user moves each tile of a scrambled image, I want to update the text of `TextView` at the same time by showing "No. of Moves"
I have designed the code to count the moves. but its in another file and i have designed a `TextView` in another file dynamically.

So, how could i get a reference and its continuously updated value from the function of another file.

There should be some method which should notify on each move. Like `nsNotification center` in `iOS`.

Comment: you should share some code if you want advice

Comment: Implement an observer pattern?

Comment: Consider restructuring your code. What you are trying to do can be encapsulated in a single activity.

Comment: code gets complicated if i use observer pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android AsycnTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)or you can use android service with broadcast receive.using this AsycnTask you can detects when you move image object within your textview.You can use doingbackground to do backgeround task and onPostExecute you can change textview.

Comment: Both files are Non-activity classes.

Comment: you mean Textviews are also in nonactivity class.can you share some of your sample code.it will be easy

Comment: ya..textview in non-activity class.

Comment: if you want to show textview in Non-Activity class you have to pass content to this class.using content you can show the Textview. so use separate class for asycn task and implements the relevant methods which i mentioned above.